# Sencha Touch - scroll to last tab on TabBar

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

There is a view with many tabs in my App. I'd like to set focus on the last one. I can set active tab `this.setActiveItem(10)`, but I'm not able to scroll (programmatically) tabbar to the last item. Content of the 10th tab is shown but 10th item on tabbar is hidden, so user could be confused.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really good question and many people may find this useful.

So first, instance of `tabBar` is needed so we can get `activeTab` of *tabPanel*. Then we can easily get the offset of tab item. Here, tab item means not the container that holds tab's contents but the tab indicator which can either is placed at top or bottom. So we just need offset of *active tab item* from `tabBar` not the container.

```
    this.getMyTabPanel().setActiveItem(6);

    var tabBar = this.getMyTabPanel().getTabBar();

    var activeTab = tabBar.getActiveTab();
    var x= activeTab.element.getX();
    var y = activeTab.element.getY();
```

Next part is, to get instance of `tabBar` scroller. Once we get this we can pragmatically scroll it do desired position we get in above step.

```
    var scroller = this.getMyTabPanel().getTabBar().getScrollable().getScroller();

    scroller.scrollTo(x,y);
```

Working [demo is here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#p1fcj)

---

**update**

You can also enable *animation* while pragmatically scrolling with -

```
scroller.scrollTo(x, y, true);
```

Comment: demo link not working.Could you please provide a working link @SachinGutte