# Scrolling tab panel's Tab Bar

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a long tabBar which is horizontal scrollable , I want the selected tab to align at left most side. For example if I select the middle the tab it should be visible at the left most side. And I have next and previous buttons to select the next and previous tabs. So if any tab right to the Left most tab is selected by clicking the prev button now it should be visible at left most side. Overall i want the selected tab to be visible at left most side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest if you have a fix size of tabButtons.
That way you could calculate on how much you have to scroll to the side.
A good start will be to set the tabBar.setScrollable({direction:'horizontal'}).

But anyways. It seems bad design for phone's or tablets. You should come up with another idea.

Comment: I have scroll direction:horizontal and also width of the tabs is auto according to the text of tab. What I tried is you can get from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685963/sencha-touch-scroll-to-last-tab-on-tabbar  but its not doing what i exactly want

Comment: Can you explain how its not doing what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it and got a solution a little trick in the activeitemchange of the tabpanel will do the task

TabPanelActiveItemChange: function (container, value, oldValue, eOpts) {

```
        var count = container.innerItems.length;
        var currentIndex = Ext.Array.indexOf(container.innerItems, value);
        var tabBar = container.getTabBar();
        // to keep the selected item in left or visible in smaller width screen.
        var totalWidth = container.innerItems[count - 1].tab.element.getX() - container.innerItems[0].tab.element.getX() + container.innerItems[count - 1].tab.element.getWidth();
        if (totalWidth > window.innerWidth) {
            var widthToScroll = container.innerItems[currentIndex].tab.element.getX() - container.innerItems[0].tab.element.getX();
            var scroller = tabBar.getScrollable().getScroller();
            scroller.scrollTo(widthToScroll, 0, true);
        }
```